# IdentityServer4 Authenticates but doesn't Authorize because context.User = null, ASP.NET + Angular 8

Tags: asp.net, angular, identityserver4, .net-5

**Using:**

1. template Angular + ASP.NET Core application from VS Studio 2019
2. Angular 8.2.12
3. .NET 5
4. MySQL backend

**Problem:**

Project implements IdentityServer4 for Authentication/Authorization but when adding a certificate to the IDS4 instance Authorization fails as `context.User` returns `null`.

**Startup.cs:**

call the certificate from certificate store:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
using (var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    // var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,"THUMBPRINT>, false);
    var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"localhost", false);
    if (certCollection.Count > 0)
       cert = certCollection[0];
 }
```

set the certificate on IdentityServer4:

```
if(cert == null)
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        //.AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
}
else
{
    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

adding Authentication & Authorization:

```
services.AddAuthentication()                
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, UserAuthorizationHandler>();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
      options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
      {
            policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            //To require the basic user_impersonation scope across the API, you can use:
            //policy.RequirePermissions(
            //    delegated: new[] { "user_impersonation" },
            //    application: new string[0]);
       });
       options.AddPolicy("LocalAuthorizationPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserRequirement(CustomRoleTypes.SiteAdmin)));           
});
```

The certificate gets correctly found and assigned to the IDS4 instance.
User Authentication proceeds correctly and user gets redirected to the correct location.
User is able to call General -non authorized- Controller methods.

When controller method is decorated by `[Authorize]` the controller returns a `401` error.
Because the user is not recognized within the context and returns null.
(i.e. `AuthorizationHandlerContext` as well as `IHttpContextAccessor` return null for `ClaimsPrincipal`)
The latter does not happen when IDS4 is instantiated using no SigningCredentials.

i.e. when using:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()   
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

it all works correctly...

I have checked the returned `user` using the `LocalAuthorizationPolicy` and determine if there is a `user` identified in the request context.

I have searched many sites for a walkthrough on the ideal implementation but so far have not been able to find the solution.

I noticed that there are several posts that recommend installing IdentityServer as its own project . But haven't been able to implement that yet...

Any advise would be appreciated.